# What is negative sampling method use- sigmoid or softmax?

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, word2vec

I am recently reading this paper: Word2Vec explained(https://arxiv.org/pdf/1402.3722.pdf)

And there's something I can't understand..

In page 3, they say that p is defined using softmax

$p(D=1|w, c, \theta) = \frac{1}{1+e^{-v_c\dotv_w}}$

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l1m5Y.png)

but i am confused because i have seen that formula in sigmoid function, not softmax function.

How you derive that definition from softmax?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be called a small abuse of notation on the author's part but it's totally fine. Sometimes people use the softmax and sigmoid interchangeably. However, in this case it is indeed a sigmoid function because of binary class problem.

Comment: Thank you so much! I am newbie to this area soI didn't know that people use the softmax and sigmoid interchangeably.